# SFDX - No org configuration found for name

Tags: salesforcedx, vs-code, sfdx-plugin

Suddenly vscode stopped working with deploying the class to the sandbox I'm using and throws this message "No org configuration found for name INSTANCE NAME"

I tried to create a new project for the sandbox but still get the same error when I'm trying to retrieve all the classes from the org.

sfdx update didn't help.

Comment: It sounds like you need to authenticate again? Try `sfdx force:auth:web:login -a "some-alias" -r https://test.salesforce.com/ -s` (change `some-alias` to whatever you'd like to call the sandbox).

Comment: Sometimes it might be a proxy issue.

Comment: Don't have enough reputation to add an answer, but my issue was that I was pasting in a username with capital letters into my deployment command.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Deleting folders "tools", "typings" and the file "sfdx-config.json" and then close and open vscode solved the problem.

Comment: I tried this, then re-authorize and organization using command `SFDX: Authorize an Org`. It is working. But why? Care to do some explanation? Or it is just a caching issue?

Comment: It also worked for me.. Anyone knows what is the cause of this?

Comment: I don't think you even have to delete the tools or typings folders, because just restarting VS Code was enough to fix it for me (after everything else I tried failed). There must be something in the cache that gets stale after refreshing sandboxes or updating org aliases, because restarting VS Code seems to always do the trick. Would be nice to understand more though

Answer (score 25):

It may be a problem with **aliases**.

I have mistakenly created an alias: 
`DevHub=me@salesforce.com`

Then, not aware of consequences I created an alias again, in the way I wanted it in the first place: `me@salesforce.com=DevHub`

So I ended up having two aliases, which were translated by the CLI:

```
DevHub -> me@salesforce.com -> DevHub
```

So CLI was trying to use `DevHub` as my username, instead of `me@salesforce.com`

Hence, the error: `No org configuration found for name DevHub`

Verify Your aliases with:

```
sfdx force:alias:list
```

and delete unnecessary aliases (if any) by setting them as empty:

```
sfdx force:alias:set DevHub=
```

Comment: THIS IS THE BEST ANSWER AND SHOULD BE SELECTED AS ONE IN THIS PAGE. IMG moderators should be more strict on letting people selecting their own answer as the best answer even though they're not. This page's selected answer doesn't even provide any explanation.

Comment: @Bahman.A Moderators have no control over answer acceptance. It's completely at the discretion of the asker.

Answer (score 4):

One of the reasons may be conflict in your aliases files. You can find following folder on your computer: `%USERPROFILE%/.sfdx` and find there file `alias.json`. There would be all your used aliases and you can investigate if you have any conflicts.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem just now, working with a developer sandbox and indeed authenticating again solved the issue. Thank you

Comment: authenticating again did not help.

Comment: authenticating again worked for me

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem this week and this is how I solved it:

1. open the .sfdx folder and manually delete the org configuration file
2. remove the alias reference in the alias.json file
3. re-auth into the org in a new terminal window

Answer (score 1):

FYI, this happened to me.  Specific error I got was: "No org configuration found for name DevHub"

I used the command: `sfdx force:config:list` to see my configuration values for *defaultdevhubusername* and *defaultusername*.   I noticed that *defaultdevhubusername* was just DevHub so I changed this to the username I used to login to my DevHub and it worked.   To change, I used command `sfdx force:config:set defaultdevhubusername=myusername@domain.com`

Hope this helps someone else.