# Why can't I authorize my sandbox in my SFDX environment?

Tags: salesforcedx, sandbox, authentication

I have a recently refreshed sandbox built against our production org. I need to authorize my SFDX environment so I can push the source code to it. I've executed these shell commands:

```
% sf org login web --alias MySandbox --instance-url https://ourdomain--mysandbox.sandbox.my.salesforce.com
Successfully authorized user@domain.com.mysandbox with org ID 000000000000000000

% sf org display --target-org MySandbox --verbose

=== Org Description

 KEY              VALUE                                                                                                                                                          
 ──────────────── ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── 
 Access Token     0000...                                               
 Alias            MySandbox                                                                                                                                        
 Api Version      59.0                                                                                                                                                           
 Client Id        PlatformCLI                                                                                                                                                    
 Connected Status NamedOrgNotFoundError                                                                                                                                          
 Id               000000000000000000                                                                                                                                             
 Instance Url     https://ourdomain--mysandbox.sandbox.my.salesforce.com                                                                                                      
 Sfdx Auth Url    force://PlatformCLI::000...@ourdomain--mysandbox.sandbox.my.salesforce.com 
 Username         user@domain.com.mysandbox
```

So I'm being told that the sandbox is successfully being authorized, but then I'm told that the connected status is "NamedOrgNotFoundError." How do I fix this?

A few more potential clues:

- I thought of just starting over and executing `sf org delete sandbox --target-org MySandbox`, but this results in `Error (1): The target org, ourdomain.com.mysandbox, is not a sandbox.` But `sf org list` shows that org has no expiration, so it's not a scratch either (?). (Note that `MySandbox` is my current default org as I'm doing this.)
- Since it's being reported that it's not a sandbox, I thought I'd try `sf org delete scratch --target-org MySandbox`, but that errors with `Error (1): No authorization information found for MySandbox`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/255985/sfdx-no-org-configuration-found-for-name), the answer was a circular alias reference. I had tried to `sf alias unset` for my `MySandbox` alias, but there was also an alias from the user name to the `MySandbox` alias, and unsetting this fixed the problem (or more accurately, `sf alias username=` worked).